# Changing button classes in Angular UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/bGxF8dG5WUiBXzHYRO5m?p=preview) I have an Angular UI Datepicker that uses a template. I need to change the colors of the "Today", "Clear" and "Close" buttons but changing them in `popup.html` doesn't work. It should show gray, orange and blue buttons.

I changed from

```
<li ng-if="showButtonBar" class="uib-button-bar">
  <span class="btn-group pull-left">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info uib-datepicker-current" ng-click="select('today', $event)" ng-disabled="isDisabled('today')">{{ getText('current') }}</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger uib-clear" ng-click="select(null, $event)">{{ getText('clear') }}</button>
  </span>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success pull-right uib-close" ng-click="close($event)">{{ getText('close') }}</button>
</li>
```

to

```
<li ng-if="showButtonBar" class="uib-button-bar">
  <span class="btn-group pull-left">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default uib-datepicker-current" ng-click="select('today', $event)" ng-disabled="isDisabled('today')">{{ getText('current') }}</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning uib-clear" ng-click="select(null, $event)">{{ getText('clear') }}</button>
  </span>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right uib-close" ng-click="close($event)">{{ getText('close') }}</button>
</li>
```

Note that I changed the button class names to change the color, but when I inspect in the browser, the datepicker is still using the old classes. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a *custom popup* template use `datepicker-popup-template-url` attribute, for example:

```
<input datepicker-popup-template-url="popup.html"  type="text" class="form-control" is-open="true" ng-model="dt" uib-datepicker-popup="MM-dd-yyyy"
            datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" popup-placement="bottom-left" on-open-focus="false" />
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/fa6AUZ4i0cKJKMqmby5l?p=preview)